# "Working" for someone outside the US no legal paperwork

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I'm a US Citizen working for someone outside the US. Technically and Legally speaking, I don't work for them at all, there were no forms signed, contracts, etc. It's just something I do on the side, but I have been making an income higher than $400.

I was wondering what I should report this as in my taxes, a gift? I don't technically work for them, and it's a somewhat strange situation.

Here's some info:
1. I'm a minor (16 years old), this is my first time filing taxes.
2. I am a US Citizen.
3. The person that pays me lives in Spain.

Remember, I'm not on the company payroll, or in any part of the companies legal documents.

Comment: You do something for this person, and in exchange they pay you? If so, you are indeed working for them, paperwork or not. It's income to you, you'd file it on a Schedule C, and you can offset it with any expenses incurred.

Comment: Yeah I guess you can say that. There are absolutely no documents supporting the job however. Not sure what it means to be employed in terms of taxes.

Comment: When you're an employee, your employer has obligations for withholding and paying taxes. This isn't the case for you, but you do get paid for work done, so you are self-employed as far as the IRS is concerned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reinforce the @HartCO comments: the IRS considers you a self-employed independent contractor.

https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/schedule-c-form-1040-profit-or-loss-from-business

> Use this schedule to report income or loss from a business you operated or a profession you practiced as a sole proprietor. An activity qualifies as a business if:
>
> - your primary purpose for engaging in the activity is for income or profit, and
> - you are involved in the activity with continuity and regularity.